# How do I get only all full matches when multiple groups are required in regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get only all full matches in a string, but it needs multiple groups.

```
import re 

coordParse = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]\s*\(\d+(\.\d+)?,(\s)*\d+(\.\d+)?\)')
n = 'a(3.43, 5834) b (84, 45.89) C(48, 36.)'

print(coordParse.findall(n))
```

findall returns:

```
[('.43', ' ', ''), ('', ' ', '.89')]
```

what I want is:

```
['a(3.43, 5834)', b (84, 45.89)]
```

Group only returns the first match. Is there some way to return only all full matches?

Comment: Just use non-capturing groups.

Comment: Wiktor is referring to `(?:)` For example `((?:foo)..(?:bar))` to match `"fooX1bar"` and set the complete match as group 1